# On the Example of J. Alperin

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In the paper "[Large Abelian Subgroups of $p$-Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1994193)" by J. Alperin, the author constructs an example of a $p$-group of order $p^{3n+2}$ ($p>2$) in which any abelian subgroup has order at most $p^{n+2}$. The group is described as follows: let $H_1=\langle w,z_x,z_y\rangle$ be elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^3$. Let $H_2=\langle H_1,y\rangle$ where $y^p=1$, $y$ commutes with $z_x,z_y$ and $y^{-1}wy=wz_y$. Let $H=\langle H_2,x\rangle $ where $x^p=1$, $x$ commutes with $z_x,z_y$, $x^{-1}wx=wz_x$, $x^{-1}yx=yw^{-1}$.

Then $H$ is a group of order $p^5$ (for $p>2$) such that

i) $Z(H)\cong C_p\times C_p$

ii) $[H,H]\cong C_p\times C_p\times C_p$ and $Z(H)<[H,H]$.

Let $G$ be the [central product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_product) of $n$ copies of $H$ ($n\geq 1$). Then $G$ is a group of order $p^{3n+2}$, which contains abelian subgroup of order $p^{2n}$ but does not contain abelian subgroup of higher order.

**Question** Suppose $H$ is replaced by another group of order $p^5$ satisfying conditions as in (i) and (ii), i.e if $K$ is a $p$-group of order $p^5$ such that $Z(K)\cong C_p\times C_p$, $[K,K]\cong C_p\times C_p\times C_p$, $Z(K)< [K,K]$, and $G_1$ is central product of $n$-copies of $K$, then do we have similar conclusion for $G_1$ for orders of maximal abelian subgroups?

Comment: Do you mean that $G$ has an abelian subgroup of order $p^{n+2}$ and none of higher order?

Comment: @Derek Holt: yes.